# JSON Serialization giving unexpected error

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

im trying to deserealize a NSData to NSARRAY or NSDICTIONARY but NJSONSERIALIZATION is giving me Error 1. I've us the method many times successfully but i don't know why in this particular case is not working.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [WebMethod GetMenuForRestaurant:restaurantid];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

NSData *responseData;
NSError *error = nil;

for (int c = 0; c<5; c++) {
    //make the request
    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    //some hardcode
    if (responseData!=nil)
        c = 10;
}

if (responseData==nil)
    return nil;
NSDictionary* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Here is my json:

```
{"Sections":[{"sectionname":"Main","Products":     [{"ProductName":"hamburguer","Price":250.0},{"ProductName":"pasta","Price":300.0},{"ProductName":"pizza","Price":350.0}]},{"sectionname":"desserts","Products":[{"ProductName":"brownie","Price":200.0},{"ProductName":"helado","Price":150.0}]},{"sectionname":"entries","Products":[{"ProductName":"chips","Price":125.0},{"ProductName":"salad","Price":100.0},{"ProductName":"weed","Price":1000.0}]}]}
```

Trying to deserealize it, the json serialisation gives me this error:

```
(<invalid>) [0] = <error: expected ']'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's your JSON? Why do you have the download in a loop and the usage outside the loop?

Comment: The response data its define outside the loop. The loop its just to make the request until 10 request are made or the response its != null. Yes im sure im using the the jsondata here > 

NSDictionary* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

Comment: Why make the same request multiple times? Can you paste the full error text. Why is the response coming back as `nil`?

Comment: Here in dominican republic, sometimes the internet is not so stable... so sometimes the request can't make it to the api, so i send it till i get the response... something else, the cellphone may  be connected to the 3g network, which sometimes is unstable

Comment: i did something that worked out, i set options to NSJSONWRITINGPRETTYPRINTED, but it shows a warning even working... is there any other way

Comment: Pretty printing isn't even an option for JSONObjectWithData -- it maps to NSJSONReadingMutableContainers.  What are you *really* doing?  (Add `NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData];  NSLog(@"JSON string = %@", jsonString];` and show us what it prints.)

Comment: I'm guessing you have several problems.  Show us more of the code (especially where you check and print the `error` parm from NSJSONSerialization), and copy/paste the *exact* error/warning messages you get.

Comment: This is the jsonstring: 

{"Sections":[{"sectionname":"Main","Products":[{"ProductName":"hamburguer","Price":250.0},{"ProductName":"pasta","Price":300.0},{"ProductName":"pizza","Price":350.0}]},{"sectionname":"desserts","Products":[{"ProductName":"brownie","Price":200.0},{"ProductName":"helado","Price":150.0}]},{"sectionname":"entries","Products":[{"ProductName":"chips","Price":125.0},{"ProductName":"salad","Price":100.0},{"ProductName":"weed","Price":1000.0}]}]}

Comment: what im trying to do is to get the response from a http get to a api....

Comment: That JSON is bogus.  Paste it into an online JSON parser to see.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure but it appears that some invalid characters have snuck in there.

Comment: Around "350.0" and "200.0" are some invalid non-printing characters.  Also around "productName":"chips".

Comment: it looks like the invalid characters are the "/n" o <br> jump lines, i pasted the json directly to the parser and its totally working